# WP create custom table and insert data in front end

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, forms

Im trying to make a custom form and insert into the database but when I click submit nothing happens. Please help me. I did research and changed my code but still same result. I dont know why. 
Thanks.

this is the code in my template named std:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Student
*/
get_header();
?>

<?php echo "google";?>

<?php

    if($_POST['Submit']){

global $wpdb;

$name=$_POST['aname'];
$roll=$_POST['aroll'];
$dept=$_POST['adept'];


if($wpdb->insert(   
    'std',
    array(

            'name' => $name,
            'roll' => $roll,
            'dept' => $dept
        )
) == false) wp_die('Database insertion failed');
    else echo "Database insertion successful<p />";

?>
<?php
}
else //else we didnt submit the form, so display the form
{
?><form action="" method="post" id="addcourse">

<label> Student Name:<input type="text" 
name="aname" size="30" /></label>

<label> Roll:<input type="text" 
name="aroll" size="30" /></label>

<label> Department:<input type="text" 
name="adept" size="30" /></label>

<BR>

<input type="Submit" id="addcoursesubmit" value="submit" />
</form>
<?php
}

{
}
?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Nothing like really nothing? Form does not get submit?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. yes. it will just refresh the page if i click submit. and nothing save in my database.

Comment: probably a prefix? `$wpdb->prefix . 'std'` Turn you error reporting on

Comment: I just forgot to put name in submit button. thank you so much for the answer.

Comment: That is a simple typographical error you made, good to see you were able to figure it out. Also this is considered off-topic which just means you can safely delete your question it won't get missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put name on your input submit.

```
<input type="Submit" id="addcoursesubmit" value="submit" name="Submit"/>
```

Comment: wow. hands down. thank you so much. It works!! i just forgot that name. godbless

Comment: That's great. :)